# Django: How can i validate the combination existance of two fields?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I'm using Django Model Form. Can anyone help me validate those fields to get field error using clean()?

The **Name** field cannot be repeated in the same office, only in a different one.

form.py

```py
class CreateSalesRepForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CreateSalesRep
        fields = ['name', 'office']

        widgets = {

        'office': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Office'}),
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Name'})

        }
```

**UPDATED** (form.py) --- Here is the solution, you can use this codes to validate both insert and update form.

```py
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        office = cleaned_data.get("office")
        name = cleaned_data.get("name")
        duplicates = CreateSalesRep.objects.filter(office=office, name=name)
        if (self.instance.pk and None):
            duplicates = duplicates.filter(pk=self.instance.pk)
        if duplicates.exists():
            msg = "Name already exist in office selected"
            self.add_error('name', msg)
            self.add_error('office', msg)
```

view.py

```py
def create_salesrep(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateSalesRepForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved!', 'alert-success')
            return redirect('sales_rep')
        else:
            return render(request, 'salesrep/create_salesrep.html', {'form':form})

    else:
        form = CreateSalesRepForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'salesrep/create_salesrep.html', context)


def update_salesrep(request, pk):
    srep = CreateSalesRep.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = CreateSalesRepForm(instance=srep)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateSalesRepForm(request.POST or None, instance=srep)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Updated!', 'alert-success')
            return redirect('sales_rep')
        else:
            return render(request, 'salesrep/update_salesrep.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        form = CreateSalesRepForm(instance=srep)
        return render(request, 'salesrep/update_salesrep.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate in the forms:

```
class CreateSalesRepForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
         model = CreateSalesRep 
         fields = ['name', 'office']
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        office= cleaned_data.get("office")
        name = cleaned_data.get("name")
        duplicates = CreateSalesRep.objects.filter(office=office, name=name)
        if self.instance.pk:
            duplicates = duplicates.filter(pk=self.instance.pk)             
        if duplicates.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Name already in office')
```

That being said, you could enforce this in the model/db level as well by adding the following to your `CreateSalesRep` model:

```
class CreateSalesRep(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['office', 'name']
```

Comment: Show us your templates

Comment: Good to hear. self.add_error would be a valid solution as well.

Comment: Hi, I have one more challenge, when i update and give the name and office that are arleady exist it accept duplicate. How can i prevent that from update form?

Answer (score 1):

You can try following inside your model class

```
class Meta:
        unique_together = [('office', 'name')]
```

Comment: I was wrong. This will be handled in the form. This warning alludes to it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method. Here's the formal documentation on the model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique